# Do I need to pass through a controller when getting data to a view with Ajax in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my javascript code I have the following:

```
function SelectTopics() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Administration/Loc/SelectTopics",
        data: { DataSourceID: $('#DataSourceID').val(),
            LocationID: $('#LocationID').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#TopicID').html(data);
            $('#SubTopicID').html("<option value='00'>All Sub Topics</option>");
        }
    });
}
```

In my controller code I have:

```
    public string SelectTopics(string dataSourceID, string locationID)
    {
        return Select.Topics(
            dataSourceID, 
            locationID);
    }
```

In the Select class I have the following:

```
    public static string Topics(string dataSourceID, string locationID)
    {
        ...
        return text;
    }
```

The controller is just passing through a request and my controller code is getting bigger with all these requests. Is there another more conventional way of getting data into a view from a data source without going through the controller each time?

Comment: In MVC the convention *is* to go through a controller. This seems silly for very simple requests where it acts as a pass-through but as the system grows and you need to add security, session/state management, et cetera the controller comes in handy since it prevents polluting the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC definitely requires a `Controller` class to handle all requests.  You cannot simply expose the `Select` class without it inheriting `Controller`.  There might be a way, though, to minimize the amount of "pass-through redundancy" in your controller.

#### Simple Reflection

If your methods take the same parameters, you could use reflection and clever routing to get the results you're looking for.

For example, the url `/Administration/Loc/Select/Topics?dataSourceId=x&locationId=y` could be routed with `/Administration/{Controller}/{Action}/{Method}` to:

```
public ActionResult Select(string method, string dataSourceID, string locationID) {
    var methodInfo = typeof(Select).GetMethod(method);
    return methodInfo.Invoke(dataSourceID, locationID);
}
```

#### MVC Routing

If the methods take different parameters, then it would be pretty tedious to use reflection to map inputs to the parameters.  A huge portion of the MVC framework is in the Routing.  It  does a lot of reflection to do the mapping from the request to the Action method, and it would be pretty tedious to recreate this functionality.

It might be possible to use the MVC routing engine to pass the requests to the controller.  This might be a great solution, but it definitely takes a lot more research than I have time for, sorry.  The good news, though, is that MVC is open source, so you could definitely see how they do it!